# How to add paginations on 5000 products in html with jquery?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have list with 5000 products in HTML and want to add pagination with jquery. I have added simple pagination but this creates problem. It shows list with 347 pages together. i want to show only 10 pages numbers then next, previous.
I have used this one in codeigniter.

```
$("ul.paging").quickPager();
```

Please let me know any solutions.

Comment: are you using  CI pagination?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this on your jQuery code

```
 $('#pagination-demo').twbsPagination({
    totalPages: 35,
    visiblePages: 7,
    onPageClick: function (event, page) {
        $('#page-content').text('Page ' + page);
    }
});
```

And HTML code:

```
<ul id="pagination-demo" class="pagination-sm"></ul>
```

For more help you can visit this: [jquery Pagination](http://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/)

Mark this as answer and vote up if this answer gives you the help.

Comment: I have tried this one. This is adding content dynamically. But i want like show 10 rows in first page then others on another page..

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution...

$('#example2').paginate({itemsPerPage: 30});